# Alinear Texto en Python

Tags: python

soy nuevo en esta página y necesito ayuda para poder hacer un juego en CMD (Terminal).

```
print("""Decide lo que vas a hacer:

        1) Opcion 1.                         2)Opción 2.
        3) Opción 3.         4) Opción 4. """)
```

Lo malo es que en la consola sale desalineado y no se como hacer para que las opciones se vean bien.

Aquí una foto de como me sale el CMD:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero que salga todo el texto sin que baje a la linea de abajo, es decir, que el texto salga de una y que no tenga que bajar a la linea de abajo...
es la configuración de mi CMD por el tamaño de la letra o se puede modificar?

Comment: Modificando la parte de la cadena donde dice "2)Opción 2", el menú me aparece perfectamente alineado. Lo que deseas es que "decide lo que vas a hacer" y las opciones estén en la misma cordenada x?

Comment: A que te refieres con las coordenadas??, voy a hacer edit para mandar como me sale a mi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay muchísimas formas, pero yo optaría por utilizar `\n` que es equivalente a ¶. Es muy útil para no tener que usar la triple comilla. Y también puedes usar `\t` que seria una tabulación.

Código:

```
print("Decide lo que vas a hacer:\n\t1) Opción 1.\t2)Opción 2.\n\t3) Opción 3.\t4) Opción 4. ")
```

Salida:

```
Decide lo que vas a hacer:
    1) Opción 1.    2)Opción 2.
    3) Opción 3.    4) Opción 4.
```

Comment: Yo esque el texto que le pongo es un poco largo y me hace lo mismo como aparece en la imagen. Tengo que reducir texto o que puedo hacer para que no me salga así como en la imagen.

Comment: Ya he podido solucionarlo añadiendo \n en cada opción así se ve mucho mejor. Gracias por tu ayuda @nadie