# Python: No puedo poner los 2 textos en la misma linea

Tags: python, python-3.7

Ya intente como mover la lista de manga arriba, para que este al mismo nivel de lista de animes, pero nada, porfa ayuda.
[image: La lista de manga no lo puedo subir arriba al mismo nivel de lista de anime]

Acá dejo el código Python:

```
#!C:\python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

def manga_lista(anime):
  for i in anime:
    print(i, "\t")
manga_lista("Lista de animes")

def anime_lista(manga):
  for index in range (len (manga)):
      print("\t", manga[index])
anime_lista("Lista de mangas")
input()
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Alinear Texto en Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/469270/alinear-texto-en-python)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Por defecto al hacer `print()` se agrega un salto de línea, para sobre escribir este comportamiento puedes utilizar el argumento `end` de `print()`

Ejemplo:

```
print("Hola!", end = ' ')
print("Soy yo.")
```

Resultado:

```
Hola! Soy yo.
```

En el argumento `end` pones el caracter que se va a utilizar en lugar del salto de línea, en el ejemplo anterior fue un espacio vacío

Comment: No me sale, ya lo intente con los caractes de /n, /t y /, pero no me sale. Acá dejo el codigo: